# Iframe inside iframe to access its own cookies

Tags: cookies, iframe, cross-domain, fetch-api

I have some authentication cookies on the top site.

Inside it an external domain iframe is rendered. And inside the iframe we add another iframe from the top level domain.

In our iframe we need to access the cookies but we get just empty value.

The cookie is SameSite: Lax, Secure: none, HttpOnly: false

I had tested with set `credentials: 'include'` on the fetch request - does not work

and with `sandbox='allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-forms'` on the bottom iframe - still nothing.

Is there a way to allow the iframe has access to the cookies?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to read the cookie on the parent and then place it in local storage for the iframe to read it.